# Determine value based on criterias

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have measured gas emission from jars in a long time series. My data set consists of three columns: `date`, `time` and `jar`.
The jars were measured in a time series according to first "a" then "b" and then "c", but I don't have this information in my dataset. Therefore I want to make a new column in my data set that says if the jar were measured according to "a", "b" or "c".

The things I have tried so far has not given the expected outcome.
Any ideas?

The data looks like this:

```
df <- structure(list(date = c("2021-03-14", "2021-03-14", "2021-03-14", 
"2021-03-14", "2021-03-14", "2021-03-14", "2021-03-14", "2021-03-14", 
"2021-03-14", "2021-03-14", "2021-03-14", "2021-03-14", "2021-03-15", 
"2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", 
"2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", 
"2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", 
"2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", 
"2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", 
"2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", 
"2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", 
"2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", 
"2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", 
"2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", 
"2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", "2021-03-15", "2021-03-15"
), time = c("23:55:00", "23:56:00", "23:57:00", "23:58:00", "23:59:00", 
"00:01:00", "00:02:00", "00:03:00", "00:04:00", "00:05:00", "00:06:00", 
"00:07:00", "00:08:00", "00:09:00", "00:10:00", "00:11:00", "00:12:00", 
"00:13:00", "00:16:00", "00:17:00", "00:18:00", "00:19:00", "00:20:00", 
"00:21:00", "00:22:00", "00:23:00", "00:24:00", "00:25:00", "00:26:00", 
"00:27:00", "00:28:00", "00:29:00", "00:30:00", "00:31:00", "00:32:00", 
"00:33:00", "00:34:00", "00:35:00", "00:36:00", "00:37:00", "00:38:00", 
"00:39:00", "00:40:00", "00:41:00", "00:42:00", "00:43:00", "00:44:00", 
"00:46:00", "00:47:00", "00:48:00", "00:49:00", "00:50:00", "00:51:00", 
"00:52:00", "00:53:00", "00:54:00", "00:55:00", "00:56:00", "00:57:00", 
"00:58:00", "00:59:00", "01:00:00", "01:01:00", "01:02:00", "01:03:00", 
"01:04:00", "01:05:00", "01:06:00"), jar = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L
), expected.outcome = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-68L))
```

Comment: What is the logic to get a, b, c from `jar` value?

Comment: Well, it's bit technical, but let's just say that in the first and second time series of jar 1 and the first time series of jar 2 and 3, "gas a" was added to the jars. In the third and fourth time series of jar 1 and the second time series of jar 2 and 3 "gas b" was added to the jars and so forth. Measurements were made every five second or so. If a jar has not been measured for minimum 40 minutes then the time series is over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal seems to be adding a new column based on the change of the column "jar".

- If all the necessary information were available inside a row to calculate the value for your new column in that row, it would be easier and you could just briefly define a new data.table column, perhaps with two "ifelse". For example:

```
dt <- data.table::data.table(df)[, Gas:= ifelse(CONDITION1, "a", ifelse(CONDITION2, "b", "c"))]
```

- Here, however, it seems the value also depends on other rows, so I don't think there's a one-liner that would solve it.

For example, with your data, it seems every time jar jumps from 3 to 1 from one row to the next, your expected.outcome changes to the next letter. (I'm not sure that is the exact logic you're looking for because you mentioned time series that change after 40+ minutes, in which case you would need to make changes.) Based on that criteria, you could create a loop to run over the data frame and establish the new column bit by bit.

So the code addition below would reproduce the expected outcome.

```
addGasVector <- function(df)
{
  gases <- c("a", "b", "c")
  
  #initial values
  Gas <- vector() #will become a new column
  previousJar <- 0
  currentGas <- "a"
  
  #loops through every row to create a new column        
  for (row in 1:nrow(dt))
  {
    currentJar <- df[row, "jar"] 
    
    #criteria you identify for a change of gas, change accordingly
    if (previousJar == 3 & currentJar == 1)
      currentGas <- gases[match(currentGas, gases) + 1] #change of gas to next letter

    Gas <- c(Gas, currentGas) #adds the new column item
  
    previousJar <- currentJar #for the next iteration
  }
  
  df <- cbind(df, Gas) #adds the new column
  
  return(df)
}

View(addGasVector(df))
```